# How to Join two tables with Count , GROUP BY & Join in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with data inserted into each;

address:

```
INSERT INTO Address (Address_ID, DoorNumber, Street, City, Postcode)
VALUES (1, "26", "Basketball Lane", "Surrey", "SW4 0DF"),
       (2, "2", "ONCE Housing", "Surrey", "PO9 3HJ"),
       (3, "18", "Petits Filous Road", "Surrey", "BA2 7JW"),
       (4, "7A", "Sanpei Heights", "Surrey", "SAN 1HJ"),
       (5, "10B", "Forehead Road", "Surrey", "PO9 3HZ"),
       (6, "9B", "Golden Gate Towers", "Surrey", "BF5 LQZ"),
       (7, "12f", "Hudson River", "Surrey", "GG5 LFZ"),
       (8, "9B", "Sora Close", "Surrey", "AG5 LFZ");
```

accommodation_details:

```
INSERT INTO Accommodation_Details (AccomDetails_ID, Room_No, Band, 
            Availability, Total_Cost, Address_ID)
VALUES (1, "1A", "A", "N", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "Basketball Lane")), 
       (2, "1B", "A", "N", 6950, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "Basketball Lane")),
       (3, "1C", "A", "N", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "Basketball Lane")), 
       (4, "1D", "A", "Y", 6950, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "Basketball Lane")),
       (5, "1E", "A", "N", 6950, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "Basketball Lane")),
       (6, "2A", "B", "N", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") ),   
       (7, "2B", "B", "Y", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") ),
       (8, "2C", "B", "Y", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") ),
       (9, "2D", "B", "Y", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") ),
       (10, "2E", "B", "Y", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") ),
       (11, "2F","B", "N", 7000, (SELECT Address_ID FROM Address WHERE Street = "ONCE Housing") )

.... ;
```

I want to be able to represent the total number of "tenant" living at each address (from accommodation_details) like so:

```
        Tenants:
Basketball Lane | 5 |  (number of tenants with fk of 1 in accomDetails from address)
Once Housing    | 6 |
 ...
```

I attempted to do this through grouping by address_id in accommodation_details

```
    SELECT Address_ID, SUM(Address) AS "Total Tenants",
FROM accommodation_details AS accomDetails
JOIN Address ON accomDetails.Address_ID = Address.Address_ID
GROUP BY Address_ID;
```

but it gives me a "AddressID is ambiguous" error, how can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it. My mistake was that I was selecting fields from the AccommodationDetails table first when I wanted to also access the Street field (to print it out) as well as grouping by Address_ID when I needed to GROUP BY the Street instead (to see how many tenants were living in a dorm on a street)

```
    select Street, count(addr.Address_ID) as total_tenants
    from address as addr inner join accommodation_details as acc on 
    addr.Address_ID = acc.Address_ID group by addr.Street;
```

Note: I have used `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN` but this shouldn't matter since both return values that match in **both** tables.

Doing this gives me:

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| Street             | total_tenants |
+--------------------+---------------+
| Basketball Lane    |             5 |
| ONCE Housing       |             6 |
| Petits Filous Road |             5 |
| Sanpei Heights     |             5 |
| Forehead Road      |             1 |
| Golden Gate Towers |             1 |
| Hudson River       |             1 |
| Sora Close         |             1 |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

which is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

- `Address_ID` exists in two tables, qualify it with which table it is, just as you did in the `ON` clause.
- `SUM(Address)` does not make sense since `Address` is only a table name.  `COUNT(*)` would count the number of rows.  I see no way to turn that into "tenants" to adjust for 2 in a room.

Comment: the column room_no can be assigned to the same address repeatedly because the relationship is many dorms to one address with one tenant to one dorm.

Comment: @zkhan122 - I'm having trouble with your terminology.  When I went to school there were 2 persons per dorm room and several dozen rooms per dorm.  And multiple dorms at the University.  The dorm had a street address (and city).  To send postal mail to me, one needed the address + room number + my name to uniquely get to me.

Comment: by dorm i mean dorm room